# Wp all import Variable Subscription Workaround?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

Having trouble importing or creating the Variable Subscription to Woocommerce, here i send a screenshot of my issue

Woocomerce Variable Subscription
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppLNu.png

Wpallimport
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwsBH.png

Wp doesn't detect the Variable Subscription on Woocommerce, is there a workaround to this issue or is it not compatible?

I also sended a support ticket to the wp all import team, but unfortunately they are out and hoping to get an answer until monday or tuesday.

Comment: It's not clear to me what the issue is. Variable subscription is missing from the drop-down during the import? That may be because the plugin doesn't support these.